# svn keyword replacement: is it possble to replace $Rev$ with only the revision number

Tags: svn, keyword

In an html template file I would like to append the revision number to links to external css and javascript files. Pretty similar to: [IE6 Javascript problems with $Revision$ in the filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683058/ie6-javascript-problems-with-revision-in-the-filename)

But as said there, this can cause problems, at least in IE6.

Rather then replace (or extend) the keyword `$Rev$` to `$Rev: 123$`, I would prefer `123` as a result, making a link `….css?$Rev$` to `….css?123` instead of `….css?$Rev: 123$`.

Is there any template somewhere for the keyword replacement that could be modified?

Comment: Did my answer help you in 2013? Please, upvote and accept it then. :)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't change the output format of a keyword. With Subversion 1.8 and older client, the keyword output format is always `$keyword: value $`.

See [SVNBook | Keyword Substitution](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html).

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but the subject is still interesting today:
I had the same question in PHP, and this is what I did:

```
if (preg_match('/^\$Rev: (\d+) \$$/', '$Rev:$', $bits)) {
    echo "Version = ", $bits[1];
}
else {
    echo "Version = unknown";
}
```