# Subversion to Update the ver in a text file

Tags: c#, c++, svn, version-control

I am in a circular trap here...
We are building on a dedicated server, so when we do a pull and build I want to update the version information in the projects to show a version such that the last digit is the "revision" number at that current pull for subversion.

But if the script updates that file, then it is not current.  So I need to re-commit that file, or merge it in the next pull, or ...?  Then the revision number is incremented.

I solved it in a C++ program by placing the actual revision numbers in a file that was NOT under the control of SVN.  Now the script can "svn update", capture the revision number, change the local file, and built.  However that creates a dependency on a file that is not under SVN control.

Furthermore, there are projects where it appears I cannot externalize the version number into a dedicated file, and leave that file out of SVN control.

What I really would like to see is a "eyecatcher" tag that SVN would update upon an svn commit (or svn update).  Something arbitrary like:  {!SVN_REV}
So, my C# assembly file might look like this:

```
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.1.0.{!SVN_REV}")]
```

Other version control systems support this kind of ability. Is there anyway in Subversion to do it?

Thanks for any advice.
Scotty

Comment: [Keyword Substitution](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html)

Comment: I'd like to know too! We version control that file; PITA. What I really need is a practical solution where I can inject the desired version number (via ANT or a VS setup project or Jenkins or ?) and have it propagate in the build process such that when we install, Windows "programs and features" shows that new version number.

Comment: Related: [svn keyword replacement: is it possble to replace $Rev$ with only the revision number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20004339/svn-keyword-replacement-is-it-possble-to-replace-rev-with-only-the-revision-n/25143282#25143282)

Answer (score 0):

> if the script updates that file, then it is not current

No, it's *current* (it terms of information), you can just not save this minor change in repository (best and easiest way)

From other side, you can

- Store template-file in repository (read about SubWCRev and it's keyword)
- At build stage create additional not versioned file at first stage with keywords, substituted with real (actual data) and use *this* file, not template

Comment: Okay, semantics...   The _repository_ is not current, so developers do have access to it.  The script I have does an update, then builds. Then it should commit this change back?   If I have to re-commit just for a number increment, then it's counting up pointlessly.  Because if I run it again, I'll have a new revision number that isn't associated with any real change or fix.  Which is what I am trying to avoid.  Currently, I am just going down the path of a non versioned file that replaces keywords in the versioned one.

Comment: " Then it should commit this change back?" - never. Just `svn revert` this change in file